# Is there an environment that acts the same way as framebox?

Tags: environments, tcolorbox

I am trying to make a `tcolorboxenvironment`. Without the package `tcolorbox`, I want to have an environment that acts the same way as `declarenewentry`:

```
\newcommand{\declarenewentry}[1]{\medskip\noindent\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\qquad #1}\medskip}
```

This will be my question:

> Is there an environment that acts the same way as `framebox`?

Comment: Should category code changes work inside your environment (should there be any verbatim content)? And should the environment allow automatic linebreaks or behave really just like `\framebox`?

Comment: Yes, just like `\framebox`, though I am not sure about the category code since I have no idea about that.

Comment: Boils down to: Do you want to use `\verb|<stuff>|` inside the environment or not?

Comment: No, there should be no verbatim content.

Comment: You can also use the environ package and `\fbox{\BODY}`.  Of course, the entire text will be implemented as a single line.

Comment: @JohnKormylo that's essential the same as my `\NewDocumentEnvironment` solution, but yes, that would be possible as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following shows two different approaches how you could collect the contents of the environment. The first one (`declarenewenryENV`) uses `lrbox` to collect stuff inside a box, and then inserts the box contents into your `\framebox` (I just called `\declarenewentry` inside the environment for convenience).

The second approach (`otherENV`) collects the environment body as an argument. That approach is much simpler to code, but doesn't allow verbatim material (so no `\verb`) inside the document body.

Overall the second approach should be preferred, imho, if support for `\verb` isn't necessary.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newsavebox\declarenewentryBOX
\newenvironment{declarenewentryENV}
  {\begin{lrbox}\declarenewentryBOX}
  {%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \declarenewentry{\unhbox\declarenewentryBOX}%
  }
\newcommand{\declarenewentry}[1]
  {\medskip\noindent\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\qquad #1}\medskip}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{otherENV}{b}
  {}
  {\declarenewentry{#1}}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\blindduck
\declarenewentry{abc is def}
\blindduck
\begin{declarenewentryENV}
  abc is def
\end{declarenewentryENV}
\blindduck
\begin{otherENV}
  abc is def
\end{otherENV}
\end{document}
```

All three calls (macro, environment collecting a box, environment collecting the body as an argument) show the exact same behaviour in the small test document shown above (you should probably add a `\par` before `\medskip` in your `\declarenewentry` macro).

Result:

[image]